# Returning a locally created const char*

Tags: c++, pointers, return, lifetime, string-literals

```
#include <iostream>


const char* fun()
{
    const char* x = "abc";
    std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    return x;
}


int main(int arc, char** argv)
{
    const char* y = fun();
    std::cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Running this on my machine gives:

```
x = abc

y = abc
```

In `fun()`, `x` (a local variable) is assigned the address of a string literal created locally, yet when the function returns, the data pointed to by `y` is the same as that pointed to by `x` even though `x` is out of scope.

Can someone explain in detail what is happening here?

Comment: The point you are missing is *a function may always return a value of its own type*. The caveat with pointer is *what they point to must still exist after the function returns*. @songuyanyao explains below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is well-formed, the returned pointer is valid and not dangled; because the [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (i.e. `"abc"`) has static storage duration and exists in the whole life of the program.

> String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

As you said when the function returns the local variable `x` gets destroyed, but the string literal pointed to by it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As to you function `fun`

```
const char* fun(){
    const char* x = "abc";
    std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    return x;
}// the pointer returns but it's content still alive, because it points to string literal
```

If you change function `fun` to the below:

```
const char* fun(){
    char x[] = "abc";
    std::cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    return x;
}// the pointer returns but it's content died
```

then:

```
const char* y = fun();
std::cout << "y = " << y << "\n";
```

output as expected(y is ''):

[image]

Because the above `const char* x = "abc";` is not local variable, it's `string literal` which has static storage duration and exist in the whole life of the program.

On opposite `char x[] = "abc";` is local variable which will get died when out of scope.

Comment: You are only 1/2 right. It doesn't matter whether it is `char x[]` or `char *x`, it is the `"abc";` that is the important point. `"abc"` is a *sting literal* created in the `.rodata` (read-only) data segment. No matter how you declare `x`, `return x` returns a pointer containing the address of the first character in the literal.

Comment: I just give it for example. For better understand.

Comment: OK, the statement *"On opposite char x[] = "abc"; is local variable which will get died when out of scope."* is unclear. (it appears your use of *"On opposite"* was an attempt at *"Inapposite*" see [Merriam-Wester](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inapposite))

Comment: There is no "as expected" for a program with undefined behavior. Anything might happen, including working exactly the same as a correct program. I'd say something instead like "Not surprisingly, this program acts differently:".